# Cannot access file on Unix server

Tags: spring, unix, websphere

I have deployed a war file on WAS server. War file needs to access a properties file placed on Unix server. Although the file is present but I am still getting file or directory doesn't exist in the path name error.
Was and properties file both are present on same server and user has all the rights.
I am using spring placeholder tag to access file in xml.

Answer (score 0):

are you using a relative or absulte path.. if you are using a relative path maybe  you need to check your code again.

Comment: I am using absolute path. For instance, my WAS is at /usr/was and file is kept at /usr/was/test/context.properties. In code I have used placeholder of spring to access this path still m getting file or directory not correct